# pagination in flutter not loading data correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

am using flutter paging plugin for pagination in my app like this:

```
Future<List<KCSamplesModel>> pageData(
  BuildContext context, int previousCount) async {
print("called!!!!!");
List<KCSamplesModel> dummyList = List();

if (formsPageNumber < totalFormsPages && _firstOpen == false) {
  print(formsPageNumber < totalFormsPages);
  print(_firstOpen);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0, milliseconds: 1000));
  await getForms(context, false, "").then((onValue) {
    dummyList = allForms;
  });
} else {
  print(_firstOpen);
  _firstOpen = false;
  dummyList = allForms;
}
debugPrint("news_dummyList" + dummyList.length.toString());

return dummyList;
}

Pagination<KCSamplesModel>(
                pageBuilder: (currentSize) =>
                    pageData(context, currentSize),
                itemBuilder: (index, item) {
                  .....
                })
```

My problem is that when i first enters the page .. page 0 is loaded successfully and i got this printed

```
flutter: called!!!!!
flutter: true
flutter: news_dummyList10
```

i scroll to the end and i got the page 1 loaded successfully and i got this

```
flutter: called!!!!!
flutter: true
flutter: false
flutter: news_dummyList20
```

and then i scroll to load more nothing will happen and pageData is not even called! i go back and return to the page and scroll page 2 will be loaded successfully and then again scroll will do nothing i go back and scroll it will load one more page and so on!

how to solve this and why its happening?